# What does the method '0x110bbd8d' on Ethereum Blockchain do?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, etherscan

When looking at new liquidity pairs under Etherscan, I often notice that there are numerous transactions/interactions with the contract shortly after the liquidity is made available.

I noticed the "0x110bbd8d" method, which finally put me on the track of Boba Builder or rsync_Builder - unfortunately I still didn't understand what Boba Builder & rsync Builder are used for and whether they are responsible for the many transactions.

To me it looks like a payment is transferred to multiple wallets created just for this purpose and then sent directly to the final destination.

Could that actually be the background and if so, what options are there for implementing this?

Here is a link to an example history: https://etherscan.io/tokentxns?a=0x2c93cff2f2a96c4b540f26204e9fdfe67f1ed5e3&p=60

I would like to understand what the background of the many simultaneous transactions is?

I look forward to any feedback and hope my first contribution here corresponds to the desired form

Kind regards